# Which version of MinGW should I use

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, mingw

I am a beginner programmer.

I want to use MinGW to develop C and C++ programs for Windows.

I have taken a basic C programming course which taught how to use Visual C++ 2010 Express.

But I want to use open source programming tools instead of Microsoft's tools.

There are 3 websites which provide installers for MinGW.

www.mingw.org

tdm-gcc.tdragon.net

http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Which of these is best for a beginner to use ?

Edit: I decided to install the latest MinGW from Nuwen.net.

How do I install pkg-config and should I install MSYS ?

Comment: If I were beginner programmer, I better took care about build system (make, ld, pkg-config), rather than compiler itself.

Comment: I would just go with any MinGW version shipped by a decent IDE like Code::Blocks, it should be reasonably recent and working (and you also get an IDE).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [MinGW-builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/) and [MinGW Distro](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html)

*In my experience current version of tdm-gcc (`tdm-gcc-4.7.1-2`) has many bugs and you'll need many patches (strings, threads, ...) choose between other choices.*

*Another choice is the MinGW beside Qt package which is tested well, but the version is not the most recent.*

Answer (score 0):

Out of those, I like nuwen, but in all fairness, I think the best beginner C program to use is lcc-win

You can find it here.

http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/

Hope this helps