# g++: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp

I use g++ (GCC) 4.7.2. on Windows 7, 64-bit version.

downloaded from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

I tried to use the "-fopenmp" flag and got the error:

g++: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory

I can't find the file anywhere on my system. Do I need to re-install something? Can I just throw a file somewhere?

Comment: I am going crazy, nothing I try is working!

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download), which looks as though it includes OpenMP.

There's also [Sezero's personal build](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/).

Comment: Getting the same error as before. Removed the old PATH to my old installation as well. Doing g++ --version displays g++ (tdm64-1) 4.7.1

Comment: TDM worked for me, note it includes openmp, but you have to explicitly select it during install

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I got it working installing one of the version at the following discussion. 
[Which version of MinGW should I use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384348/which-version-of-mingw-should-i-use)

I don't have access to my windows machine now so I don't know which version I used but I can check on Monday if you don't have it working by then.
It might have been this one.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/